# Rewritable dynamically-typed value as a class member

Tags: c++, polymorphism, reference

(This is sort of a long-winded question but I have summarized it at the bottom.)

I want to write a class (in C++) that performs tests on objects of some unknown type deriving from a very skeletal base class.  The idea is that an object of this class is initialized with an "expected" result and then called many times, saving the outcome and comparing it to the expected one.  The whole package should look something like this:

```
struct test_input
{
  virtual ~test_input() = 0;
};

struct test_output
{
  virtual bool operator== (const test_output&) = 0;
  virtual ~test_output() = 0;
};

typedef test_output& (*test_function)(test_input&);

class test
{
  const test_input &data;
  const test_output &expected;
  test_output *result;

  test(test_input &i, test_output &o)
    : data(i), expected(o), result(NULL)
    {}

  bool operator() (test_function &trial)
    { return *(result = &trial(data)) == expected; }
};

// Example usage
class ti_derived : public test_input { /* ... */ };
class to_derived : public test_output { /* ... */ };
to_derived& some_function_one(ti_derived &arg) { /* ... */ }
to_derived& some_function_two(ti_derived &arg) { /* ... */ }

ti_derived ti; // Somehow initialized
to_derived correct; // Somehow determined
test test_object(ti, correct);
if (!test_object(&some_function_one)) {
  cout << "1: " << test_object.result;
}
if (!test_object(&some_function_two)) {
  cout << "2: " << test_object.result;
}
```

My intention is that the same object of type `test` can be called repeatedly on many `test_function`s, which is why its member `result` must be a pointer rather than a reference: I can't reassign a reference.

The problem is that the code for `operator()` is wrong: the left-hand side is not a reference to a `test_output`, so it is statically cast to the exact class `test_output`, which is purely virtual; however, I want `operator==` to be dynamically bound to the equality operator for type `to_derived`.  As is, it will try to downgrade `expected` to the base type `test_output` and complain that I don't have such an operator (and if I did, it would be the wrong one anyway).  Note: switching the order of the operands would cause `operator==` to be that of `to_derived`, but then the compiler would complain that the type of the second argument was wrong.

I guess I could make `test` a template depending on types, say `template <typename I, typename O>`, replacing `test_input` and `test_output` in its code, but that is not so good because it fails to specify that `I` and `O` inherit the virtual functions I want (which is why I have those two classes in the first place).

It's tempting, though sort of inelegant, to want to overload `operator==` on type `test_output*`, but that's not legal, is it?  I could make only one of the arguments a pointer, since `expected` can remain a reference type, but again: inelegant.  This is not how I would write the code if I did not need `result` to be reassignable, and so it is not how I want to write the code.

If this were not in a class, I could just define a new reference variable every time I want to save a new `result`, but I can only have so many members.  Syntactically, this sounds like a situation where I'd want a "pointer to a reference to `test_output`", but that's illegal also.  (Either that, or something like a "`rebind`" operator for references.)  A `test_output **` is no good, since I want to ultimately be able to pass objects of (base) type `test_output`; if I do one dereference I just get a `test_output *`, but if I do two then the type is no longer dynamic.

So how do I do this?  Specifically, I want:

- to bind the equivalent of `operator==(*result, expected)` to the equality operator for the dynamic types of these things;
- to be able to indicate to the compiler that those types are derived from `test_output`;
- to be able to reassign `result`.

I am also wondering: in my sample usage, is it valid to use those function pointers as arguments to `test_object`?  Their arguments can be dynamically typed but I don't know whether that means the function type itself has an automatic conversion to the function type taking and returning the respective base types.  If not, how would I indicate a function of this dynamically-typed signature?

Comment: A further problem is that you functions take a non-const reference, but `data` is const.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but the design seems to be flawed in several aspects. First,

```
typedef test_output& (*test_function)(test_input&);
```

calls for trouble. Don't return references to objects generated inside a function. The referenced object is destroyed, when the called function ends, so you will store in `result` the address of an object that does not exist anymore (dangling pointer). If you need polymorphic results, return them safely as `shared_ptr<test_output>`, which should also be the type of `result`.

Concerning your list of questions (sorry for long answer):

> to bind the equivalent of operator==(*result, expected) to the equality operator for the dynamic types of these things;

Yes, as you did. The equality test should be overridden for every class derived from `test_output`.

> to be able to indicate to the compiler that those types are derived from test_output;

For comparing polymorphic objects for the left operand with polymorphic objects on the right hand side, welcome to the field of *multi-methods*. The problem boils down to: "When do you consider two objects as equal?" Should they have exactly the same type or can one belong to a subset of the other? Normally the *Liskov substitution principle* in object orientation means: A derived object can be substituted for a base object, since inheritance guarantees it has all base properties.
To determine if `expected` to be of (at least) `to_derived` you need a *downcast*:

```
bool to_derived::operator==(const test_output& expected)
{
  if (to_derived* e = dynamic_cast<to_derived*>(&expected))
  {
    // compare all data fields, then
    return true; 
  }
  return false;
}
```

If you want to guarantee `expected` to be of **exactly** the same type, you should use [RTTI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information) first:

```
  if (typeid(*this) != typeid(expected)) return false;
```

Derived objects are no consired of the same type. Maybe your compiler needs a switch to enable that.

> to be able to reassign result.

Use a `shared_ptr<test_output>`, because it manages memory for dynamic objects.

> is it valid to use those function pointers as arguments to test_object? Their arguments can be dynamically typed but I don't know whether that means the function type itself has an automatic conversion to the function type taking and returning the respective base types. If not, how would I indicate a function of this dynamically-typed signature?

The function pointers does not need any conversion.
But your test framework seems to be incomplete, since it may work only for standalone functions. What about methods? I would suggest a templated solution.

I would seriously consider looking for an [existing unit testing framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#C.2B.2B).

Comment: You say that `operator==(*result, expected)` *does* call `operator==(to_derived&, to_derived&)` and not `operator==(test_output&, test_output&)`?  So if I have `to_derived: public test_output {int x;}` with the natural equality, and if `expected` has `x = 0` and `some_function_one` returns something with `x = 1`, does my code print the diagnostic or not?  It seems to me it would not: the type of `*result` is determined at compilation to be `test_output` and so `operator==` is bound to `operator==(test_output&, test_output&)` whose obvious definition is always `true` (and ignores `x` anyway).

Comment: @Ryan : No, `(*result).operator==(expected)` is called because `test_output::operator==(const test_output& )` was declared as *member* function. However, it's a pure virtual (abstract) method. So you *have to* implement that operator for derived classes, otherwise you couldn't instantiate `to_derived` objects. A meaningful `to_derived::operator==` function body would then compare `this->x == e->x`. Since the base class `operator==` is declared *virtual*, the type of the left operand `*result` is determined at *runtime* (late binding). That's the basic idea of dynamic polymorphism.

Comment: What do you know, I've been fooled.  I thought that when you dereferenced a pointer to a base type it stopped being polymorphic, but a few quick tests show that what you say is true: it still gets the right virtual method.  So basically, the `*` operator returns a reference bound to the pointed-to object.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you change,

```
{ return *(result = &trial(data)) == expected; }
```

To simply,

```
{ return trial(data) == expected; }
```

That should call a proper `virtual bool operator == ()`. Do you really need `result` ? From your code, I don't feel you need it.

**Edit**: If you want `result` for diagnostics then make it a `bool`:

```
bool result;  // = false (default)
//...
{ return result = (trial(data) == expected); }
```

For some purpose if you still want `&trial()` function address, then you can store a function pointer to that as well. So ultimately you are introducing just an extra `bool` variable.

Comment: I do need it: I print `result` as a diagnostic if the test fails.  Assume for the sake of the question that I must save the result, even if the sample application I gave is not very compelling.

Comment: @Ryan, you can make it `bool` as well, see my answer.

Comment: That's not how I want to do things, though.  The state of a `test` object after calling it should reflect the outcome of the test.  It defeats the purpose of using encapsulation if I have to selectively record bits of that in external variables just to mollify a syntactic restriction.

Comment: Also, in the original code, the `&trial` was not a function pointer but a pointer to the value `trial(data)`.  My question about the function pointers was that I am passing something of type `to_derived& (*)(ti_derived&)` as an argument of type `test_output& (*)(test_input&)`, and would like to know whether there is a conversion that makes that legal.

Comment: @Ryan, `bool result` is not an external variable. It's a class member only. I haven't written the full class as I thought it's implied.